# Resizing and rotating a QGraphicsItem results in odd shape

Tags: qt, rotation, resize, transformation, qgraphicsitem

I can't understand how scaling and rotation are applied to `QGraphicsItem`.

I need to be able to apply rotation and scaling (**not necessarily keeping aspect ratio**) and I get fully unexpected results.

Rotation must be around the item center. I seem to have no problem doing that - yet if I try to debug the bounding rectangle, I get seemingly wrong values.

If I don't keep aspect ratio, instead of rotation I get a very weird skew, and I have been struggling for quite a while to find the cause and correct it. I hope anybody can find a solution.

For many items - like rectangles - my solution was to give up on resize - and just replace the item with a new one of given size.  [I even did that for pixmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31858730/1217150) (though it probably will affect performance a lot).
But I don't know how to do that for text, or a few other types (svg...).
I am trying to understand how scaling is applied, on rotated items, and how to get it applied correctly.

The code below is an experiment where I scale and rotate a text item, and the result... see attached image

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>

void experimentScaling(QGraphicsScene* s)
{
    QGraphicsTextItem* ref = new QGraphicsTextItem();  // a reference, not resized
    ref->setPlainText("hello world");
    s->addItem(ref);
    ref->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::red);
    ref->setRotation(45);

    QGraphicsTextItem* t = new QGraphicsTextItem();    // text item to be experimented on
    t->setPlainText("hello world");
    s->addItem(t);

    QTransform transform;                    // scale
    transform.scale(10, 1);
    t->setTransform(transform);
    t->update();

    QPointF _center = t->boundingRect().center();
    qDebug("%f %f %f %f", t->boundingRect().left(), t->boundingRect().top(), t->boundingRect().right(), t->boundingRect().bottom());   // seems to be unscaled...

    t->setTransformOriginPoint(_center);    // rotation must be around item center - and seems to work even though the bounding rect gives wrong values above
    t->setRotation(45);        // skewed
    t->update();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene s;
    QGraphicsView view(&s);
    s.setSceneRect(-20, -20, 800, 600);
    view.show();
    experimentScaling(&s);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Reference (red) text rotated 45 degrees, text rotated 45 degrees and resized 10,1:

[image: reference text rotated 45 degrees, text rotated 45 degrees and resized 10,1]

The resized (black) text should have the same height as the reference (red) - yet is much taller;
The bounding rectangle is no longer a rectangle - it is skewed;
The angle looks much smaller than 45;

Added a resized but not rotated reference as well:

[image]

Please help me understand why this behavior is happening and what can I do about it.

I have tried looking into `QGraphicsRotation` but I can't figure out how to apply it... All I get is a move instead of rotation.

Comment: Is that transform.scale(10, 1) correct? Shouldn't it be transform.scale(10, 10) ?

Comment: @juzzlin: I don't want to keep aspect ratio. I am trying to stretch the text in one direction or both

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As documented, the item's transformations are mathematically applied in a certain order - this is the order you'd be multiplying the transform matrices in and is, conceptually, the *reverse* of the order you'd normally think of.

1. The `transform` is applied. The origin point must be included in the transform itself, by applying translations during the transform.
2. The `transformations` are applied - each of them can specify its own center.
3. `rotation` then `scale` are applied, both relative to `transformOriginPoint`.

When you set `transform` to scaling, and set `rotation`, the rotation is performed before scaling. The scaling applies to the rotated result - it simply stretches the rotated version horizontally in your case.

You need to somehow enforce the reverse order of operations. The only two ways to do that are:

1. Stack the transforms in correct order and pass them to `transform`, or.
2. Pass a list of correct transformations to `transformations`.

I'll demonstrate how to do it either way, in an interactive fashion where you can adjust the transform parameters using sliders.

To obtain the correct result using `transform`:

```
QGraphicsItem * item = ....;
QTransform t;
QPointF xlate = item->boundingRect().center();
t.translate(xlate.x(), xlate.y());
t.rotate(angle);
t.scale(xScale, yScale);
t.translate(-xlate.x(), -xlate.y());
item->setTransform(t);
```

To obtain the correct result using `transformations`:

```
QGraphicsItem * item = ....;
QGraphicsRotation rot;
QGraphicsScale scale;
auto center = item->boundingRect().center();
rot.setOrigin(QVector3D(center));
scale.setOrigin(QVector3D(center()));
item->setTransformations(QList<QGraphicsTransform*>() << &rot << &scale);
```

Finally, the example:

[image: screenshot]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/graphics-transform-32186798
#include <QtWidgets>

struct Controller {
public:
   QSlider angle, xScale, yScale;
   Controller(QGridLayout & grid, int col) {
      angle.setRange(-180, 180);
      xScale.setRange(1, 10);
      yScale.setRange(1, 10);
      grid.addWidget(&angle, 0, col + 0);
      grid.addWidget(&xScale, 0, col + 1);
      grid.addWidget(&yScale, 0, col + 2);
   }
   template <typename F> void connect(F && f) { connect(f, f, std::forward<F>(f)); }
   template <typename Fa, typename Fx, typename Fy> void connect(Fa && a, Fx && x, Fy && y) {
      QObject::connect(&angle, &QSlider::valueChanged, std::forward<Fa>(a));
      QObject::connect(&xScale, &QSlider::valueChanged, std::forward<Fx>(x));
      QObject::connect(&yScale, &QSlider::valueChanged, std::forward<Fy>(y));
   }
   QTransform xform(QPointF xlate) {
      QTransform t;
      t.translate(xlate.x(), xlate.y());
      t.rotate(angle.value());
      t.scale(xScale.value(), yScale.value());
      t.translate(-xlate.x(), -xlate.y());
      return t;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   auto text = QStringLiteral("Hello, World!");
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QGraphicsScene scene;
   QWidget w;
   QGridLayout layout(&w);
   QGraphicsView view(&scene);
   Controller left(layout, 0), right(layout, 4);
   layout.addWidget(&view, 0, 3);

   auto ref = new QGraphicsTextItem(text);         // a reference, not resized
   ref->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::red);
   ref->setTransformOriginPoint(ref->boundingRect().center());
   ref->setRotation(45);
   scene.addItem(ref);

   auto leftItem = new QGraphicsTextItem(text);    // controlled from the left
   leftItem->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::green);
   scene.addItem(leftItem);

   auto rightItem = new QGraphicsTextItem(text);   // controlled from the right
   rightItem->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
   scene.addItem(rightItem);

   QGraphicsRotation rot;
   QGraphicsScale scale;
   rightItem->setTransformations(QList<QGraphicsTransform*>() << &rot << &scale);
   rot.setOrigin(QVector3D(rightItem->boundingRect().center()));
   scale.setOrigin(QVector3D(rightItem->boundingRect().center()));

   left.connect([leftItem, &left]{ leftItem->setTransform(left.xform(leftItem->boundingRect().center()));});
   right.connect([&rot](int a){ rot.setAngle(a); },
                 [&scale](int s){ scale.setXScale(s); }, [&scale](int s){ scale.setYScale(s); });
   right.angle.setValue(45);
   right.xScale.setValue(3);
   right.yScale.setValue(1);

   view.ensureVisible(scene.sceneRect());
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for the very clear explanation - and for showing me how to use the transformations (`QGraphicsRotation` and `QGraphicsScale `)

Comment: I also have a similar problem with this (your example) as I do with using transformations: if I try to "pin" scaling to top let, the object also moves - I am experimenting with translating it back (using m31, m32) but getting inconsistent results... Is there a way to compensate for the translation without messing up the center-based rotation ?

Comment: @Thalia Pin the scaling in which coordinate system, at what point? The systems can be the parent or the text item's.

Comment: The item's coordinate system, boundingRect().topLeft()... I added a sample in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356453/scaling-a-rotated-item-based-on-top-left-moves-the-item

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make that work by using two separate QTransforms and multiplying them together. Note that the order of transformations matter:

```
QTransform transform1;
transform1.scale(10, 1);

QTransform transform2;
transform2.rotate(45);

t->setTransform(transform1 * transform2);
```